# Global variable within export function not accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like update a variable in case the user set the language manually in a web interface (ReactJS). However I cannot access that variable in my export function.

I tried already to use different combinations of "export" (also for the variable), but nothing worked.

File: index.js

```
export function getLanguage() {

  console.log(languageManuallySelected);

}
```

Expected result: false

Actual result: undefined

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

As far as I can see, that is not a`Global Export`, that is just an `export`. You will need to `import {getLanguage} from 'file.js'`

Comment: are you sure the global variable `languageManuallySelected` was initialized to `false` ?

Comment: Are you using something like webpack to compile your code together? Global variables don't really exist at that point, unless you manually assign `window.languageManuallySelected`

Comment: edit the question putting the entire file `inedex.js` showing the declare of var

Comment: Sorry, I saw that I missed to write the actual attribute. So the whole example would be (all in file index.js, so no import necessary).

```var languageManuallySelected = false;

export function getLanguage() {

  console.log(languageManuallySelected);

}
```

I think @Peter-Cheng answered in the right way. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the variable `languageManuallySelected` is not defined in the scope of the function you are exporting. To fix this, you need to export the enclosing function with `languageManuallySelected` in its scope. A very generic example would look like this

```
export function someFunction () {
    languageManuallySelected = false;
    function getLanguage() {
        console.log(languageManuallySelected);
    }
}
```

To call it

```
import someFunction from './someFile';
someFunction.getLanguage();
```

should print 'false'

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough context in your question, but I will try to guess.

Maybe you need to refer `window` as a global scope to access your variable:

```
export function getLanguage() {

    console.log(window.languageManuallySelected);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can be assumed is a wrong pathname.

Or you are not simply destructuring the func whilst importing.

At FIRST GLANCE I CAN ONLY BE ASSUMED LIKE THIS, SINCE YOU HAVEN'T PROVIDED THE RELEVANT CODES..

A live example'd be,

folder: services/utils

```
export const getValueArray = data => data.map(item => item.value)
```

and now you should import to the desired file

```
import { getValueArray } from '--correct_path_name'
```